# Specify Bitmap offset?

Tags: android, bitmap

How do I specify an offset for the bitmap that will gave me the circle in another `x`, `y` position on the canvas?

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

Paint paint = new Paint();
Rect rect = new Rect(120, 120, 150, 0);

canvas.drawCircle(size/2, size/2, size/2, paint);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Bitmap:

The second `rect` will be where the bitmap is drawn on the canvas.
Otherwise if you are drawing the entire bitmap you could use `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, paint)` Where `x` is a `float` specifying the left side position of the bitmap and `y` is a `float` specifying the top side position of the bitmap.
See [Canvas.drawBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint))

As far as the `drawCircle()` goes.  The first two parameters would be `floats` for the x and y position of the circle respectively.
See [Canvas.drawCircle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle(float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint))